# Spring web.xml errors detected when validating the file "webapp_3_0.xsd"

Tags: java, spring

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/webapp_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servletclass>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>DefaultServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I get

> Referenced file contains errors (http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/webapp_3_0.xsd). For more information, right click on the message in the Problems View 
>    and select "Show Details..."

I did, it was not helpful for me:

> The errors below were detected when validating the file "webapp_3_0.xsd" via the file "web.xml". In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "webapp_3_0.xsd" directly. However it is possible that errors will only occur when webapp_3_0.xsd is validated in the context of web.xml.

Comment: I already did, it was not helpful for me.
"The errors below were detected when validating the file "webapp_3_0.xsd" via the file "web.xml".  In most cases these errors can be detected by validating "webapp_3_0.xsd" directly.  However it is possible that errors will only occur when webapp_3_0.xsd is validated in the context of web.xml."

Comment: I've moved your comment to the question as it is relevant info.

Comment: Your xsd location is wrong. Should be `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd` instead of `http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/webapp_3_0.xsd`. You missed a `-` between `web` and `app`.